# Fan keeps turning on/off everytime I use a browser on Acer Aspire with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: acer, fan

Well I think the title is specific enough.

Some notes of what I already tried to do:

- Installed lm-sensors and added coretemp to modprobe.d
- Installed tlp

Nothing of this seemed to work. I also have acpi_osi=Linux and acpi_backlight=vendor on my GRUB.

Please, help me! Its getting really annoying listening to the sound of the fan turning on, and after 5 seconds going off. And this happens every 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers these days can be very CPU intensive and the laptop knows this when the fan comes on to cool things down, then goes off for a while until hot again...  This is normal...  You could try a different browser to see if that helps any, my personal favourite is Midori as it's very light and my laptop fan hardly comes on when using that...

Comment: Thank you, but your answer is no good.